# LEFT JOIN execution time is too long

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. one is calender and second is final_registration like below:

```
*--------------------------*
| calender_id |  datefield | 
*--------------------------*
|     1       | 2015-07-13 |
|     2       | 2015-07-14 |
|     3       | 2015-07-15 |
|     4       | 2015-07-16 |
|     -       | ---------- |
|     -       | ---------- |
|     -       | ---------- |
|     5647    | 2030-12-28 |
|     5648    | 2030-12-29 |
|     5649    | 2030-12-30 |
|     5650    | 2030-12-31 |
*--------------------------*
```

So my first table is around 5650 records.

Now the second table is my registration table where I store user information with the booking date

```
*--------------------------------------------------*
| id |  name |     booking_date    | ticket_status | 
*--------------------------------------------------*
|  1 |  RAM  | 2018-12-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  2 |  RAO  | 2018-12-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  3 |  RAT  | 2018-12-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  4 |  PAL  | 2018-11-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  5 |  TOM  | 2018-10-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  6 |  SAM  | 2018-10-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  7 |  RAT  | 2018-09-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  8 |  MAT  | 2019-12-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
|  9 |  NOT  | 2019-12-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
| 10 |  RAM  | 2019-12-24 12:54:53 |    active     |
*--------------------------------------------------*
```

Now I want to count of registration which book in 2018 break up by month wise.

```
| booking_date | countT |
|   2018-01    |   0    |
|   2018-02    |   0    |
|   2018-03    |   0    |
|   2018-04    |   0    |
|   2018-05    |   0    |
|   2018-06    |   0    |
|   2018-07    |   0    |
|   2018-08    |   0    |
|   2018-09    |   1    |
|   2018-10    |   2    |
|   2018-11    |   1    |
|   2018-12    |   3    |
```

I am using following Query and my query is giving me correct output but the issue is the execution time. It is taking too time to execution at least 10 Min.

```sql
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m') AS booking_date, 
  COUNT(final_registration.booking_date) AS countT 
FROM calendar 
LEFT JOIN final_registration ON DATE_FORMAT(final_registration.booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = 
    DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') 
  AND final_registration.ticket_status IN ('active', 'cancelled') 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y') = $year 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: Are the `datefield` and `booking_date` fields date/datetime/timestamp data types or varchar/char data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend a correlated subquery and indexes:

```
SELECT yyyymm, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM final_registration fr
        WHERE fr.status IN ('active', 'cancelled') AND 
              fr.booking_date >= c.month_start AND
              fr.booking_date < c.month_start + interval 1 month
       ) as countT
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.datefield, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
             MIN(c.datefield) as month_start
      FROM calendar c
      WHERE YEAR(c.datefield) = ?  -- PASS IN AS PARAMETER!!!
      GROUP BY yyyymm
     ) c  
ORDER BY c.yyyymm;
```

The index that you want is on `final_registration(datefield, status)`.

This has several benefits over your query:

- It can use an index for the date comparison, because no functions are used on the date column in the second date.
- It avoids the outer `GROUP BY`, which is expensive.

Also note the use of a parameter rather than munging the query with a literal value.

Comment: ...and (for instance) this... `WHERE c.datefield BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'` instead of YEAR()

Comment: Subquery in such case would even more expensive than grouping, because it will be executed once for each row of main query instead of joining.

Comment: @BitLord . . . Absolutely not.  You don't know understand how the query works with indexes.

Comment: Wouldn't this just get the count per day, and "label" each day by only it's year and month?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you could just remind why so instead of personal attack. I've got my mistake, so my apologies. But anyway grouping is not the main issue of performance lack in such a small dataset.

Comment: @BitLord . . . I did not intend that as a personal attack and am sorry if you took it that way.  I was addressing the fact that `group by` is often more expensive than a correlated subquery with an index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, dear it is working. You save my life.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that problem in indexes.
Your query would work well only in case if you have function-based index on `DATE_FORMAT(final_registration.booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d')`. I'm not sure which version of MySQL you have, does it provides such an option or not...

But anyway I bet you have a simple index on `final_registration.booking_date`. In such way your join clause is incorrect, because index will not be used. So you shouldn't convert dates into characters in order to let index work:

```
LEFT JOIN final_registration ON final_registration.booking_date = calendar.datefield
```

By the way, WHERE clause has this problem too. Always prefer to convert a parameter than a table field, e.g.:

```
WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN str_to_date(concat("01-01-", year(now())), "%d-%m-%Y") AND str_to_date(concat("31-12-", year(now())), "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend performing the aggregation before the join and actually calculating out the beginning and end the range you want and using a `BETWEEN`; using functions such as `DATE_FORMAT()` or even `YEAR()` in your where condition will ruin performance (if you don't have an index on the date field they are called on).... also, make sure you have an index on `booking_date`.

```
SELECT c.booking_year, c.booking_month, bookingSummary.countT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datefield) AS booking_year, MONTH(datefield) AS booking_month
    FROM calendar 
    WHERE c.datefield BETWEEN [firstdayofyear] AND [lastdayofyear]
) AS c 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(booking_date) AS booking_year, MONTH(booking_date) AS booking_month
        , COUNT(*) AS countT 
    FROM final_registration AS fr
    WHERE fr.ticket_status IN ('active', 'cancelled') 
        AND fr.booking_date BETWEEN [firstdayofyear] AND [lastdayofyear]
    GROUP BY booking_year, booking_month
) AS bookingSummary
USING (booking_year, booking_month)
;
```

If you have a version of MySQL that supports CTEs, you could even do without the calendar table. A CTE that generates the numbers 1-12 as "booking_month" could be used instead (and just joined with on that field).

```
WITH calendar_months AS (
   SELECT 1 AS booking_month
   UNION SELECT booking_month + 1 FROM calendar_months WHERE booking_month < 12
)
SELECT [year] AS booking_year, cm.booking_month, bookingSummary.countT
FROM calendar_months AS cm 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(booking_date) AS booking_month
        , COUNT(*) AS countT 
    FROM final_registration AS fr
    WHERE fr.ticket_status IN ('active', 'cancelled') 
        AND fr.booking_date BETWEEN [firstdayofyear] AND [lastdayofyear]
    GROUP BY booking_month
) AS bookingSummary
USING (booking_month)
;
```

Note: Treat my [field] notations as place holders for parameters; one of the reasons I'd suggest the CTE version over the first one I presented is that it has one less parameter to maintain.